# CORS error in Flask app, only reproducible from browser

Tags: google-chrome, flask, cors

I have a simple Flask endpoint and a Chrome extension that tries to call it. However, I get an error related to same-origin-policy. When I use cURL, I do not see an error.

Here are some files:

app.py

```
import logging
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

logging.getLogger('flask_cors').level = logging.DEBUG


@app.route('/headers', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def headers():
    return dict(request.headers)

@app.route('/process_url', methods=['OPTIONS'])
def handle_preflight():
    print('preflight')
    response = app.make_default_options_response()
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type'
    return response

@app.route('/process_url', methods=['POST'])
def process_url():
    print("processing")
    print(request.headers)
    url = request.form.get('url')
    # Process the URL here
    # You can perform any operations on the URL, such as scraping or extracting information
    return dict(request.headers)
    # Return the processed result
    #return f"The URL '{url}' has been processed."

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Description of my extension",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "http://localhost:5000/*",
    "contextMenus"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action === "sendRequest") {
      console.log('here')
      var currentUrl = window.location.href;
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:5000/process_url", true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
          sendResponse(xhr.responseText);
        }
      };
      xhr.send("url=" + encodeURIComponent(currentUrl));
      return true;
    }
  });
```

background.js

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Send Request",
    contexts: ["page"],
    onclick: function(info, tab) {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { action: "sendRequest" });
    }
  });
```

Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: So, your extension is trying to eavesdrop on every request by sending it to another website?  Of course that's a CORS error.  Your URL is unrelated to the URL currently being processed.

Comment: @TimRoberts my extension is going to work for chinese news sites, taking articles, assessing their reading level, and then adjusting it based on user preference (so if a news article is too advanced for me, then I will change it to 5th grade level). So in that case, I want to pass the url to the server.

Comment: Well, your code is passing EVERY web request to your server, which is going to cause performance issues.  You'll be called for every script, every image, and every stylesheet.  Regardless, you should be able to make this work by using an `Origin` header in your request, and responding with an `Access-Control-Allow_Origin` header.    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: How is it passing EVERY request? It gets triggered from a context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, couldn't reproduce the error in the browser.
But I slightly updated the code. It might help you.

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.post('/process-url')
def process_url():
    url = request.form.get('url')
    # ...
    return dict(request.headers)
```

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "My Extension",
    "description": "Description of my extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background":{
        "service_worker":"background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches":["*://*/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }],
    "permissions":[
        "activeTab", 
        "contextMenus"
    ], 
    "host_permissions": [
        "*://*/*"
    ]
}
```

```js
/** 
 * content.js 
 */
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === 'sendRequest') {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('url', request.url);

    fetch('http://localhost:5000/process-url', {
      method: 'POST', 
      body: formData
    }).then(response => response.ok && response.json())
      .then(sendResponse);
  }
  return true;
});
```

```js
/** 
 * background.js 
 */
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(async () => {
  const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true });
  if (tab) {
    const response = await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { action: 'sendRequest', url: tab.url });
    console.log(response);
  }
});

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
      title: 'Send Request',
      id: 'send_request', 
      contexts: ['page'],
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried using this code, but I still get this error:

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/process-url' from origin 'https://www.bbc.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: I still can't reproduce it. I don't get any error. But you can try to get the data in the background script. Then the attempt should not be assigned to the fetched page, which is the case with the content script.